# AWS Giving Warning on using some end point through older TLS Verions

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, tls1.2, amazon-sns

**Problem Statement:**

We have received a notification across all of our AWS accounts stating that certain AWS services are being accessed with outdated TLS versions (TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1). Below is one row of warning detail ->

> Region ->     us-east-1
> End Point ->  sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
> API Event Name ->  SetEndpointAttributes
> TLS Version ->     TLS 1
> Connection Count -> 6
> User Agent ->  aws-sdk-android/2.3.9 Linux/3.0.31-3084104 Dalvik/1.6.0/0 en_US

**Investigation Details:**
Upon thorough examination, we have determined that none of the services in our system are utilizing older TLS versions. Furthermore, we have upgraded the AWS SDK version in our Android application to support the latest TLS version.

Additionally, we have conducted an analysis of the CloudTrail Lake and CloudWatch logs, as recommended in the provided link. Within these logs, we have not discovered any instances where endpoints have communicated with AWS using outdated TLS versions within the past two years.

> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/tls-1-2-required-for-aws-endpoints/

Anyone, received such kind of warning in recent time?

Comment: Do you have an application for Android that still supports Android 4.x and below?  The Dalvik virtual machine went away in Android 5, released in 2014.  But it looks like this is using the AWS SDK for Android so it may be your application.